# Spectrum containing multiple points

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am struggling with something that I think should be obvious but I'm just not seeing it.

I'm given a $C^\star$Algebra $A$ that is not $\mathbb{C}1$.

In this setting there should exist an element $a\in A$ so that $\sigma(a)$ contains at least 2 distinct elements.

This seems somehow obvious indeed but I really don't know how to construct such an element or show its existence.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Use spectral calculus to show that a self-adjoint element whose spectrum consist of only one elements must be a multiple of the identity.

Comment: When $a=a^\star$ then $\sigma(a) \subset \mathbb(R)$. If $\sigma(a)=\{\lambda\}$ then we must have $a-\lambda 1=0$ because $||a-\lambda 1||$ should be in the spectrum of $a-\lambda 1$ which is just zero. Because $A$ is spanned by self adjoints, we have a contradiction. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just a little nitpick: A priori, $\|a-\lambda 1\|$ is not necessarily in the spectrum of $a-\lambda 1$, but one number with this absolute value is. But of course this does not make a difference if the spectrum is just $\{0\}$.